# Docker compose yml alternatives

Tags: docker, configuration, docker-compose

Yml depends on formatting for nested structures, and for inaccurate filled files it is very hard to find out all format errors that violate original meaning. Is there any alternative to yml format for docker-compose configuration file?

Comment: If the formatting bothers you, valid JSON is valid YAML, so you can write (or generate) JSON instead and Docker Compose should accept it.  In most cases indentation errors will result in errors that you should be able to catch fairly easily, though.

Comment: Easy for small files, hard for large, especially if you have many of them. My teammates break yml configs too often - very painful bug hunting each time - so I'm trying to find a replacement for each config in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR; No.

From [Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#service-configuration-reference)

> The Compose file is a YAML file defining services, networks and volumes. The default path for a Compose file is ./docker-compose.yml

Now to answer on your arguments regarding the format and the difficulty to find errors violating original meaning:

- [yamllint](https://pypi.org/project/yamllint/) is a first tool that can help your validate your overall yaml syntax (whatever the target expected format).
- `docker-compose config` will read your `docker-compose.yml` file in and report errors if it does not comply with the expected compose file format.

Comment: yamllint for (from real doctrine ORM config, formatting kept)
```
      joinColumns:
        target_id:
        referencedColumnName: id
      inverseJoinColumns:
        message_id:
        referencedColumnName: id
 ```
shows no errors, despite ORM syntax is wrong (these errors I actually mean). Thanks for your answer anyway docker-compose config is quite useful :)

Comment: yamllint is a first step to validate yaml only. Of course it will not catch any error regarding your tool expected format. If you want to validate docker-compose see above. And I am quite sure Doctrine has a tool for that (or the symfony console).

Comment: unfortunately, not able to find a validation tool for doctrine yet